# Display of blocks according to the screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, screen

I am looking for the approach about how the blocks are being displayed and being adjusted on this page
http://www.eonline.com

Js Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/3pcDe/

Thanks for any solution in advance.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery masonry is your friend

http://masonry.desandro.com/

It's a really simple to use plugin with various options

Answer (score 1):

Or, even better, take a shine to Masonry's bigger sister Isotope - she can do all sorts of tricks on top of Masonry and is as easy to handle. Both were developed and are maintained by the same developer; Masonry came first, Isotope was built as an advancement with sorting, filtering and other cool features, see and try for yourself [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).